# focus() doesn't set on input field after displaing (use refs)

Tags: reactjs, react-ref

Dumb React question: how to set focus on input after it displayed and why my code doesn't work? (Without display toggle it works.)

**edit:** What I expect: after click on a button, the input field appears (by removing .dnone class) and get a focus on it. (But it doesn't.)

My code:

```
import "./styles.css"; // with .dnone class with display:none
import React from 'react';

export default class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.input = React.createRef();
    this.state = {
      active: false
    }
  }

  click = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    this.setState({
      active: true
    });
    this.input.current.focus();
  }

  render () {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <input type="text" ref={this.input} className={(this.state.active ? "" : "dnone")} />
        <button type="button" onClick={(e) => this.click(e)}>click</button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

live demo: https://codesandbox.io/s/immutable-sea-9884z?file=/src/App.js:0-607

Thank you!

Comment: What are you trying to achieve here? `d-none` is a bootstrap class and you neither import it nor type it correctly.

Comment: there is style.css with class/style ".dnone". it's not a problem. problem: this.input.current.focus(); doesn't work

Comment: Doesn't work after clicking the `click` button?

Comment: Yes. There is click handler on button and function click() where state is changing for input class toggling and then an attempt to focus on it by this.input.current.focus();

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that React state updates are asynchronously processed, so in the click handler when you enqueue a state update you are immediately attempting to focus on the input, but since the `active` state hasn't updated yet you can't, the `dnone` classname hasn't been removed and input made visible yet.

Move the focus logic into the `componentDidUpdate` lifecycle method to "respond" to the `active` state updating.

```
componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState) {
  if (prevState.active !== this.state.active && this.state.active) {
    this.input.current.focus();
  }
}

click = (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();
  this.setState({
    active: true
  });
}
```

[image: Edit focus-doesnt-set-on-input-field-after-displaing-use-refs]